Effect of external voltage on collision time/ mobility constant
While studying velocity of a electron in a semiconductor under external bias we derived it something like this, $$v_d= a\ \tau + v_t,$$
where $a$ is the acceleration from external bias, $\tau$ is the mean time between two collisions and $v_t$ is the average thermal velocity of the electron (this is taken as zero).
The $a$ is further replaced as $a=F/m^\star = (qE)/m^\star$, where $E$ is the external bias applied and $m^\star$ is the effective mass of a electron, giving us finally $$v_d=(q\tau/m^\star)E.$$
The quantity in the brackets is now taken as mobility constant $\mu$.
My question is, is the $\mu$ truly bias independent? Charge is constant, $m^\star$ is (in my knowledge) derived from the curvature of $\text{E-K}$ diagram (which will, presumably, simply shift in presence of an external bias).
The only quantity I am unsure about is the collision time. I think it should decrease with an increase in potential as all the electrons now tend to move to a globally common point (kind of like a crowd of people just standing as compared with a crowd of people rushing to get somewhere). I tried a surface level search but whatever came up was either too advanced or it didn't answer my question.
Any help/feedback is appreciated!
